# Configure Glimpse in Code

Tags: configuration, glimpse, app-startup, webactivator

Glimpse is currently configured in the web config for MVC5 as shown below:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="glimpse" type="Glimpse.Core.Configuration.Section, Glimpse.Core" />
    </configSections>
</configuration>

<system.web>
    <httpModules>
        <add name="Glimpse" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule, Glimpse.AspNet"/>
    </httpModules>
    <httpHandlers>
        <add path="glimpse.axd" verb="GET" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpHandler, Glimpse.AspNet"/>
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>

<glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd">
    <tabs>
        <ignoredTypes>
            <add type="{Namespace.Type, AssemblyName}"/>
        </ignoredTypes>
    </tabs>
</glimpse>
```

is there anyway to configure glimpse in code perhaps using web activator or a class called from global App Start?

Comment: I thought this would be easy...Doh

Comment: Has any one managed to do this yet?